# How to know when user changes app settings

Tags: ios, notifications, nsuserdefaults, appsettings, settings.bundle

I want to know if the user changes any of my app settings from Settings app.

I tried observing `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` and the app started receiving notifications when the user changes any app settings and returns to the app. But I found out that this notification is sent also in other cases where no change is really made in Settings app (by the user) or within the code.

So I'm wondering if there is any way to ONLY detect the changes made by the user to the app settings.

Comment: for that you need to create your own notification to the value changes for specific variables...it is little bit hard too..instead of do that, you can use the current one and check is there any change for the variables you store for your settings in the "NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification" selector method..

Comment: I thought of doing that but wanted to know if there is any less hackish way.